# Extraer texto expresion regular JAVA

Tags: java, regex

Agradezco de su ayuda ya que tengo un problema que creo que puedo resolver con una expresión regular

Actualmente estoy trabajando con java y tengo un texto de la siguiente manera

```
[404] during [GET] to [http://USER-SERVICES/api/v1/1] [UserRestClient#findById(String)]: [{"timestamp":"2020-12-30T19:39:42.849+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/api/v1/1"}]
```

Quisiera extraer la ultima parte la que dice:

```
{"timestamp":"2020-12-30T19:39:42.849+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/api/v1/1"}
```

¿Como podría hacerlo? como les digo estoy trabajando con Java

Comment: Recuerda que es importante agregar lo que has intentado, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: ¿Este texto es originado a partir de un consumo REST? realizo esta pregunta ya que si es así podrías ahorrarte trabajo extrayendo el valor del body que el protocolo http te proporciona en la respuesta, seguido de construir un objeto JSON con el contenido que te interesa. Si es correcto lo que pregunto intenta colocar código del como realizas el consumo para indicarte de que manera puedes extraer el contenido de tu interes.

Comment: Con `\[({.*})\]$` incluso con `{.*}`.

Answer (score 2):

Si bien podrías usar una expresión regular yo te recomiendo este método:

```
int llaveInicio = texto.indexOf("{");
int llaveUltima = texto.indexOf("}");
string subCadena = texto.substring(llaveInicio, llaveUltima);

//Imprimo subcadena
```

La **función indexOf** nos devuelve la posición donde se encuentra el caracter que le indiquemos, en este caso nos devuelve la posición donde se encuentran los caracteres **"{"** y **"}"** y posteriormente utilizamos la **función substring** para copiar de la cadena original desde la posición de **llaveInicio** hasta la posición de **llaveUltima**, obteniendo así el resultado deseado.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: @MichaelVega, si la respuesta te fue útil podrías marcarla como aceptada y dar tu voto